# How can we Read Power is present in wire Or not in ardunio uno?

Tags: arduino

Hey guys i had very simple question .. i am new in electronics .. i am using ardunio to send alert when electricity is present or not at my home or farm ..

i don't know how i can do that .. suppose i had an adapter which gave output of 5V 1AMP  .. so how i can read that information in ardunio when power is ON in adapter .. i tried to put the RED (Anode) Wire in some  of my digital pins and analog pins with DigitalRead function and AnalogRead .. but it always returning some of values .

please help us how to tell ardunio when power is on ... i need any of modules ?? to do that ?

thanks in advance for you help sorry for bad english ....

Answer (score 0):

you don't need any modules to do this, you should connect the negative wire of your adapter to arduino gnd, then the positive wire of your adapter to any adrduino digital input/output pin for example pin 5, then you should connect a 10k resistor from pin 5 to arduino gnd "as a pull down resistor"

Arduino code:

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(5, INPUT);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT); //will use the built in led to show the result

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  power = digitalRead(5);
  if (power) { 
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH); 
    // do other things if you want
  }

}
```